# WCF Certificate custom validation - send exception message to client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a simple WCF service configured for with transport security and Certificate client credentials.
I plug a custom certificate validator to it, and throws a FaultException. 
My probkemn is the esception message does not reach the client : i only receive a MessageSecurityException without any Fault...
If i turn my service in net.tcp (self-hosted), i the receive a CommunicationExcetion, with no Fault either.

Here is a part of my web.config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" messageEncoding="Text">
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="SecureService.Server.ChunkStreamService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" name="wsHttpEndPoint" contract="SecureService.Server.IChunkStreamService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication  customCertificateValidatorType="SecureService.Server.CPSValidator, SecureService.Server" certificateValidationMode="Custom" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and my Validator :

```
    public class CPSValidator : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateValidator
  {
    public override void Validate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
       throw new FaultException("Certificate is not from a trusted issuer");
    }
  }
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: AFAIK the cert validation step occurs on a different layer - far below the fault-handling mechanisms of WCF, it occurs on the SSL level which is directly on top of TCP/IP in this case...

Comment: But i read on msdn (which obviously does not work) "Note:
To return authentication errors back to the client, throw a FaultException in the Validate method." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx)

Comment: I made a test with UserName authentication and custom validator : sending a FaultException allows to retreive the message on client side... The difference with my certificate validation is i use the TransportWithMessageCredential : could it be the point ?

Comment: something like that: UserName auth occurs on the service level while cert validation occurs on a lower level (thus on the network level which doesn't know anything about custom exceptions)...

Comment: Ok: so is there a way to do a TransportWithMessageCredential and certificate authentication ? Will it lower security level ?

Comment: is lowers the security level - if that is acceptable then do it... otherwise live with the fact that the exception in case of failed cert validation is a "standard one"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yahia and Pablo answered, certificate validation does not happens at service level. Therefore, FaultException cannot reach the client. But this is true only because i am using the transport security mode. In order to send message back to the client i had to change my security mode from Transport to TransportWithMessageCredentials, like this :

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
  <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

This way, the certificate validation is done at service level, so that an error message can be sent to the client throught a faultException.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, any exception that you throw in a validator never reaches the client. The client always receives a MessageSecurityException. Only the exceptions that happens at service level (in the service implementation) and are mapped to a FaultContract are correctly sent to the client.

Regards
Pablo.

Comment: therefore, there is no way explaining the client what happened ? (expired/revoked/not trusted...certificate, or other unknown problem)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning on WCF diagnostics on the server to catch issues in the WCF pipeline prior to the call getting to the service itself?

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="log.evtlog"  />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunatley, this gives me no more information on what's happening, and why my error messages does not come to the client side. It seems that Yahia and Pablo are right when they say the FaultContract is only at the service level.